# Faithful Operations in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find a minimum $m$ such that the group $D_4$ has a faithful operation on the set of order $m$.

I think we need to find an injective map from $D_4 \rightarrow Perm(X)$. But I am not sure how to do/find m?
Any solutions?

Comment: By $D_4$, do you mean the dihedral group of the square?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the action of $D_4$ on a set of four points, which we may view as the vertices of a square. Is this action faithful?

If so, bearing in mind $|D_4|=8$, what can we say about any homomorphism $\phi:D_4\to S_m$ for $m<4$?

Comment: Yes, the action of $D_4$ which is a Dihedral group of order 8 on vertices of a square is faithful. So, when we look for homomorphism we should consider $S_4$?

Comment: Yes. Did you figure out why $S_m,m<3$ fails?

Comment: I am not sure because in both the cases map is not going to be surjective. So, why prefer one over the other?